# Error while trying to destructure an array of possible length 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to destructure an array of length 2, but I get a typescript error:

```
[ts] Tuple type '[string]' with length '1' cannot be assigned
to tuple with length '2'.
```

---

```
    let output = {status: false};
    if(execute.permission) {
        let message: [string] = execute.params;
        if(message.length >= 2) {
            // Destructuring follows
            [output['position'], output['message']] = message;
        }
    }
```

How do I tell typescript, that the array could possiblly be of length  2?

Comment: You can use: `let message: [string, string] = execute.params;`

Comment: @Diullei they can but they shouldn't

Comment: You used a `[string]` instead of `string[]`. The former creates a tuple, and the latter creates an array. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've not declared `message` as an array; you've declared it as a tuple (`[string]`) and tuples have a fixed number of elements. (See the *Tuple* section in the [*Basic Types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) documentation.)

You could declare it as a tuple that has two string elements (`[string, string]`), but given that you are testing `message.length >= 2` it seems likely you intended to declare it as a string array (`string[]`):

```ts
let output = {status: false};
if(execute.permission) {
    let message: string[] = execute.params;
    if(message.length >= 2) {
        // Destructuring follows
        [output['position'], output['message']] = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `string[]` (an array of any length) instead of `[string]` (a ["tuple"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) limited to length 1) as your type.

Tuples have a specific length and make it easier to represent multiple types assigned to specific index positions, like `[string, number]`. Homogenous (single-type) tuples are still useful in some scenarios (such as representing pairs in a map), but are not as common.

Arrays, on the other hand, are lists of variable length but are designed to hold only references of a single type (even if that type is a union type or `any`). If one index of any array can hold a certain value, every index can hold that same kind of value.

---

### TypeScript Code ([Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20execute%20%3D%20%7B%20permission%3A%20true%2C%20params%3A%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20output%20%3D%20%7B%20status%3A%20false%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(execute.permission)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20message%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20execute.params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(message.length%20%3E%3D%202)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Destructuring%20follows%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Boutput%5B%27position%27%5D%2C%20output%5B%27message%27%5D%5D%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(output)))

```
let execute = { permission: true, params: ['a', 'b']}


let output = { status: false };
    if(execute.permission) {
        let message: string[] = execute.params;
        if(message.length >= 2) {
            // Destructuring follows
            [output['position'], output['message']] = message;
        }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I won't downvote but this is a bit off. Arrays of a union type are not uncommon (technically that is still just one type but they result from compiler inference as a heterogeneous array is built up imperatively). Also tuples containing only elements of a single type are also fairly common, for example if you get the entries of `Map<string, string>`, but I would say that creating homogeneous tuples is a practice best avoided.

Comment: A union type to me is still a type, but I do think you make a fair point about using tuples to represent homogenous pairs. I will update my answer, and I appreciate you taking the time to give me suggestions rather than downvoting and leaving without a word as so many other users often do.

Comment: I gave it some thought and your conception of an Array's type is very correct. I was conflating the use of the array as a heterogeneous container with its interface which is defined by a single type argument, whatever that may be, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type of `message` variable. Array of strings suits better than array with single string

```
let message: string[] = execute.params;
```